# MySQL - Store posts sent to large number of users

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a web app with a complementary mobile app. Let's say for the purposes of the question that the web app is used to create messages that are sent to all or a subset of the mobile app users. I'm trying to determine the best way to store these messages.

Currently, I have it set up with one table `messages` that stores the messages and another table `recipients` that stores a record for each recipient per message.

For example, if I have a message with an id of `1` which is sent to three users `alex, bill, chris`, then the `recipients` table will look like this:

```
recipients_id | message_id | username
1             | 1          | alex
2             | 1          | bill
3             | 1          | chris
```

`message_id` is the primary key of `messages` and `username` is a field in the `users` table (I'm actually using an INT PK, but just using a string for the question).

Now just imagine that instead of three users, the message is sent to a few hundred or even a few thousand users. Is this still viable? I know MySQL tables can handle millions of records, but I'm just wondering if this is the most efficient method.

Comment: Why **username** column?  Better use just two columns, message_id from a message table and  recipient_id from users table,  also a timestamp for message sent.

Comment: The username field, like I explained (or rather implied) in the question, is just there for illustrative purposes. I'm also omitting those trivial fields like created and modified timestamps. If I don't have an auto-incrementing PK for the recipients table, should the user id be an identifying relationship?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot. The reason I'm not just using message_id and user_id as a compound key is that the users are actually in two different tables (two types of users) and so there would be duplicate user_ids.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the proper method for implementing many-to-many relationships in SQL.

The only alternative is a comma-separated list. But then you're limited by the size of the column. And joining with this type of value is difficult and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, and yes I would use user_id rather than username in the recipients table. MySQL is certainly capable of handling hundreds of thousands of records like this, limited only by the amount of RAM on your MySQL server.

Then to get a list of messages sent to a specific user (eg user id 2), you could use a simple join query like:

```
SELECT * FROM recipients LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id = recipients.message_id WHERE recipients.userid = 2
```

Or to get a list of recipients for a specific message (eg message id 3);

```
SELECT * FROM recipients LEFT JOIN users ON user.id = recipients.user_id WHERE recipients.message_id = 3
```

Hope this helps :)